# Duplicate repeated rows in sql

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to execute following lines of code:

```
select 
    MIN(tr.UPC) as UPC, MIN(td.UPC) as DistUPC,   
    MIN(tr.ProductDescriptionReported) as ProductDescriptionReported,
    MIN(td.ProductDescriptionReported) as DistProdDesc,
    MIN(tr.RawProductIdentifier) as RawProductIdentifier,
    MIN(td.RawProductIdentifier) as DistRawProdIden
--into #tmpCompareData 
from 
    #tmpSTRecData tr
left join 
    #tmpSTDistData td on tr.ChainID = td.ChainID
                      and tr.StoreID = td.StoreID
                      and tr.SupplierID = td.SupplierID
left join 
    TranslationMaster tm on tr.UPC = tm.TranslationCriteria2
group by 
    tr.UPC
```

[image]

I am getting repeated rows of result.

In the attached image the yellow highlighted is output I am getting and green highlighted is output which I require.

Please Help

Comment: Simplify your problem. Add sample table data - and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: The output you are getting and the expected output are much contradictory. Kindly provide proper sample.

Comment: Don't focus on data, its for giving an idea. My issue is I am getting duplicate records like BOTA BOX MINI.. is repeating and DistUPC is blank

Comment: @RiteshGupta give us data relevant to the question and you may get a useful answer.

Comment: Please also retag your question with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: I don't understand. With `group by tr.UPC` you tell the DBMS that you want one result row per UPC and this is what you get. So what else *is* it that you want to get? One row per `DistProdDesc` maybe? I agree with Viki888; your sample doesn't make any sense, because the data doesn't match, so we don't know what exactly you want different.

Comment: @RichBenner is right. You need to provide relevant data (table structure, sample data) so that others maybe able to reproduce the scenario and thus help you. As of now, the question is very vague. Would an answer of *Use `DISTINCT`* be good enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
    tr.UPC as UPC, MIN(td.UPC) as DistUPC,   
    MIN(tr.ProductDescriptionReported) as ProductDescriptionReported,
    MIN(td.ProductDescriptionReported) as DistProdDesc,
    MIN(tr.RawProductIdentifier) as RawProductIdentifier,
    MIN(td.RawProductIdentifier) as DistRawProdIden
--into #tmpCompareData 
from 
    #tmpSTRecData tr
left join 
    #tmpSTDistData td on tr.ChainID = td.ChainID
                      and tr.StoreID = td.StoreID
                      and tr.SupplierID = td.SupplierID
left join 
    TranslationMaster tm on tr.UPC = tm.TranslationCriteria2
group by 
    tr.UPC
```

Comment: What is the difference between your code and my code. Both are same

Comment: @RiteshGupta And how is he/she supposed to provide a different query on a table whose structure he/she has absolutely no idea of?

Comment: I removed MIN() from tr.UPC since you included UPC in GROUP BY. Can you please add the current and expected output in textual format instead of images so that we get a better understanding of the problem? Mostly these images are blocked due to corporate firewalls.